# ImportError: cannot import name _iterable

Tags: python, import, python-import, tethne

I installed package tethne-0.8 (successfully on Windows 10, which worked well (that is, I could import it). Then, I started fiddling around a little bit, uninstalling the package, installing an older version, uninstalling the older version, and finally re-installing tethne-0.8. I really regret doing so (I should have known!), because now, importing tethne throws the following error:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tethne\classes\feature.py", line 8, in <module>
from tethne.utilities import _iterable
ImportError: cannot import name _iterable
```

Tethne-0.8 is said to have installed successfully and I've checked all dependencies, which are also okay. I've also looked into the feature.py file:

```
"""
Classes in this module provide structures for additional data about
:class:`.Paper`\s.
"""

from collections import Counter, defaultdict

from tethne.utilities import _iterable
try:    # Might as well use numpy if it is available.
    import numpy as np
    argsort = lambda l: list(np.argsort(l))
except ImportError:
    from tethne.utilities import argsort
```

...and the utilities.py file:

```
def _iterable(o):
    if hasattr(o, '__iter__'):
        return o
    else:
        return [o]
```

I have obviously tried googling the issue. It's driving me crazy and really hope someone has a tip!

Comment: check tethne.utilities for _iterable ?

Comment: I've edited my post. I'm sorry, I'm quite new to all this and really don't know how to go about it.

Comment: No worries at all. just was trying to dig :)

Comment: :-) Any idea what the issue might be?

Comment: I'm a bit stumped. If you are using a `virtualenv` or `conda`, I might create a new environment with a fresh install. If not, I might start using one of the two aforementioned environment managers so you have more control over your environment.  -- alternatively, if you are using python3, you could use `pip-autoremove somepackage -y` to remove the package plus dependencies and then re install the package you want. That may give you a fresh install

Comment: `import tethne`, `print(tethne)`, `from tethne import utilities`, `print(utilities)`, to make sure that the modules that you are importing are the ones you *think* that you are importing.

Comment: @CristiFati I can't run any of those commands, they all give me the same ImportError message :-(

Comment: @matisetorm I use Python 2.7 (on purpose) without an environment manager and have already tried uninstalling and re-installing the package, using pip uninstall tethne and pip install -U tethne (and tried pip install tethne as well)

Comment: No, they, don't, it's your original line that does. Place them before `import _iterable`.

Comment: It says: "ImportError: cannot import name utilities" now @CristiFati

Comment: Then, replace the last 2 statements that I mentioned by `print(tethne.utilities)`.

Comment: Damn it: "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'utilities'". Sorry, I can't move to chat yet, as my reputation is not high enough. Thanks a lot for your help @CristiFati

Comment: Does this tell you anything, @CristiFati? http://diging.github.io/tethne/tethne.html#module-tethne.utilities

Comment: https://github.com/diging/tethne/blob/python/tethne/utilities.py#L108 does have that. Most likely the version that you have doesn't. Check your file.

Comment: Please do not add the solution to your question. If you found a solution that worked best for you, then you can accept it below or answer your own question. This site encourages multiple solutions from other users, as the one that worked best for you may not work the best for someone else.

Comment: @CristiFati my file had that as well, so that was not it. I found a solution (see my edit) THOUGH I'm not entirely sure why it now works!

Comment: @K.Davis OK! Didn't know! I'll change it :-)

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found one working solution: I added the following two lines of code in the feature.py file, before importing _iterable. Now, I can import tethne successfully.

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict
from tethne.utilities import mean
```